# Error UncaughtReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```html
In this Scenario, I create a Dynamic table with reactjs.
In this, there is an input text and increment and decrement feature for resizing the table row column and create a
 checkbox to make table editable.  
Please help me to resolve this issue 
"Uncaught Error: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. 
This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React". 

   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My First React File</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>     
    <script type="text/babel">
      let cols = 0;
      let text = "";
      let all_row = 1;
      let all_col = 1;
      let dTable= "";
      let i = 0;
      let index_count = 0;
      let table_value = 1;
      class DynamicTable extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
              super(props);   
              this.state = {
                  data: 'Dynamic Table'
              }
              this.tableHead = this.tableHead.bind(this);
          };
          tableHead(top_event) {
            this.setState({data: top_event.target.value});
          }
          tableRows(rows_event) {
              text = "";
              let create_rows = 0;
              all_row = rows_event.target.value;
              dTable= document.getElementById('dynamic_tbody');
              while(create_rows < all_row) {
                  text+='<tr>';
                  for(i = 0; i < all_col; i++){
                      text+='<td>Col-1</td>';
                  }
                  text+='</tr>';
                  create_rows = create_rows + 1;
              }
              ReactDOM.findDOMNode(dTable).innerHTML = text;
              document.getElementById('dynamic_style_table').style.borderWidth = table_value;
              let tbody = document.getElementById("dynamic_tbody");
              let tr_tag = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              while(index_count < tr_tag.length) {
                  let td_tag = tr_tag[index_count].getElementsByTagName("td"); 
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < td_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     td_tag[td_index].style.border = table_value+"px solid #800000";
                  }
                  index_count = index_count + 1; 
              }
              index_count = 0;
          } 
          tableColumns(cols_event) {
              text = "";
              let create_rows = 0;
              all_col = cols_event.target.value;
              dTable = document.getElementById('dynamic_tbody');
              while(create_rows < all_row) {
                  text+='<tr>';
                  for(i = 0; i < all_col; i++){
                      text+='<td>Col-1</td>';
                  }
                  text+='</tr>';
                  create_rows = create_rows + 1;
              }
              ReactDOM.findDOMNode(dTable).innerHTML = text;
              document.getElementById('dynamic_style_table').style.borderWidth = table_value;
              let tbody = document.getElementById("dynamic_tbody");
              let tr_tag = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              while(index_count < tr_tag.length) {
                  let td_tag = tr_tag[index_count].getElementsByTagName("td"); 
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < td_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     td_tag[td_index].style.border = table_value+"px solid #800000";
                  }
                  index_count = index_count + 1; // Move to next row
    }
              index_count = 0;
  }
          tableBold(bold_value) {
              let table_value = bold_value.target.value;
              document.getElementById('dynamic_style_table').style.borderWidth = table_value;
              let tbody = document.getElementById("dynamic_tbody");
              let tr_tag = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              while(index_count < tr_tag.length) {
                  let td_tag = tr_tag[index_count].getElementsByTagName("td"); 
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < td_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     td_tag[td_index].style.border = table_value+"px solid #800000";
                  }
                  index_count = index_count + 1;
              }
              index_count = 0;
          } 
          tableColumnEdit(edit_event) {
              let edit_value = document.getElementById("edit_cell_checkbox").checked;
              let tbody = document.getElementById("dynamic_tbody");
              let tr_tag = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              if(edit_value == true) {
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < tr_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     tr_tag[td_index].contentEditable = "true";
                  }
              } else {
                  for(let td_index = 0; td_index < tr_tag.length; td_index++) {
                     tr_tag[td_index].contentEditable = "false";
                  }
              }
          }
          render() {
              let areaLeft = {
                  float: 'left',
                  color: '#800000',
                  height: '320px',
                  width: '45%',
                  border: '5px solid #333',
                  padding: '20px 20px',
                  lineHeight: '4'
                  }; 
              let areaRight = {
                  float: 'right',
                  color: '#333',
                  height: '100%',
                  width: '45%',
                  border: '3px solid #333',
                  padding: '20px 20px'
              }; 
              let fontSize = {
                  fontSize: 17,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  color: '#333'
              };
              let rows_Border = {
                  border : "1px solid #333",
                  margin: '2px 0 0 2px'
              };
              let textBox = {
                  margin: '2px 0 0 0'
              };
              return (
                  <div>
                      <form action="#" method="post">
                          <div style={areaLeft}>
                              <div class="form-group" style={textBox}>
                                  <label htmlFor="first_text" style={fontSize}>Tableable name:- </label>
                                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_text" id="first_text" value = {this.state.data} onChange = {this.tableHead}/>         
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label htmlFor="all_row_range" style={fontSize}>Range for row inc/ dec:- </label>
                                  <input class="form-control" type="range" name="all_row_range" id="all_row_range" min="1" max="5" onChange = {this.tableRows}/>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label htmlFor="all_col_range" style={fontSize}>Range for column inc/ dec:- </label>
                                  <input class="form-control" type="range" name="all_col_range" id="all_col_range" min="1" max="5" onChange = {this.tableColumns}/>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label htmlFor="bold_select_box" style={fontSize}>For Boldness of cell border:- </label>
                                  <select class="form-control" name="bold_select_box" id="bold_select_box" onChange = {this.tableBold}>
                                      <option value="0">---Please select a value---</option>
                                      <option value="1">Level-1</option>
                                      <option value="2">Level-2</option>
                                      <option value="3">Level-3</option>
                                      <option value="4">Level-4</option>
                                      <option value="5">Level-5</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                  <label htmlFor="edit_cell_checkbox" style={fontSize}>For Editing on cell of the table:-  </label>
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="edit_cell_checkbox" id="edit_cell_checkbox" value="editing" onClick = {this.tableColumnEdit}/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div style={areaRight}>
                              <table style={rows_Border} id="dynamic_style_table">
                                  <caption><h3>{this.state.data}</h3></caption> 
                                  <tbody id="dynamic_tbody">
                                      <tr id="default_row">
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-1</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-2</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-3</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-4</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-5</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr id="default_row">
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-6</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-7</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-8</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-9</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-10</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr id="default_row">
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-11</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-12</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-13</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-14</td>
                                          <td style={rows_Border}>col-15</td>
                                      </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                              </table>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              );
          }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(<DynamicTable />, document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you loading your `react` libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

Putting your `ReactDOM.render(<DynamicTable />, document.getElementById('app'));` before `<div id="app" />` makes `React` cannot find the `div`.

So,  moving `<script> ... </script>` after `<div>` should fix your problem.

Comment: I can change but not impact the same problem arise